# How to upsert MongoDB Document with DbRef using spring mongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Document
class Entity1 {
  @Id
  String id
  @DbRef(lazy=true)
  Entity2 entity2;
  String test;
}

mongoTemplate.upsert(
  new Query(Criteria.where("entity2.$id").is(entity2Id),
  new Update().set("test", "newValue"),
  Entity1.class);
```

I got `Found $id field without a $ref before it, which is invalid`

My question is: how to do this upsert with DbRef.

Comment: Hi guys, if you are going to downvote my question, please at least leave a comment and tell me why, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass entity to where query, not id. Create and save Entity2 to DB, then use entity2 instance and change your code to: where("entity2").is(entity2)